# JavaScript - Can you add a class to an Input element only if a certain condition is met?

Tags: javascript, validation, input, highlight

I am  having trouble with using JavaScript so that when a user tries to submit my HTML/CSS form while either of the input fields are blank, then the relevant field would appear 'highlighted' or outlined. My aim was to add a class (a transparent layer of some kind) to one of the input fields depending on if the field's value is blank or not. I have so far tried using: element.classList.add("className"); with no luck. The input fields are defined with no classes so I just wanted to add.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: The answer to the question in your title is yes. Why would there be restrictions on when you can add a class?

Comment: Correct I can add one of the two classes and they appear fine but when I remove the classes from the input fields I am not able to use JS to have the same class appear in the same way or in any way unfortunately.

Comment: Make sure that you don't add both classes to the same element. If they affect the same style, only one of them will be effective.

Comment: I first thought there was a problem with how I linked my JS file but other functions work perfectly fine. And it doesn't seem to be an issue of the classes clashing because not one of them appears ahaa

Comment: Add `console.log()` statements so you know which part of the code you're getting to.

Answer (score 1):

I would just loop over my inputs and check if their values are true or not, then change class name accordingly. A input's value returns false if it's blank.

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");


form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    checkInputs();
});


const checkInputs = () => {
    inputs.forEach(input => {
        if (input.value) {
            input.className = "your-class-name-1"
        } else {
            input.className = "your-class-name-2"
        }
    })

};
```

Comment: Is it possible to do what you have done for your fields and at the same time use the 'required' attribute in HTML? I guess what I'm asking is whether you can have both HTML and JS validation going on

Comment: you can use css with a pseudo-selector and change the border initially. `code` 
    input:required{
        border:1px solid rgb(246, 1, 1);
    }

Comment: Having them both on shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone told above, you should use the required parameter, but if you want to use your solution you should tell us what is not working.

I've checked your code and created a little form for this purpose like:

```
<form id='form'>
<input type="text"/ id='form-field1' placeholder='1'>
<input type="text"/ id='form-field2' placeholder='2'>
<button type='submit'/>
</form>
```

Your code:

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const a = document.getElementById('form-field1');
const b = document.getElementById('form-field2');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    checkInputs();
});

function checkInputs() {
    const aValue = a.value.trim();
    const bValue = b.value.trim();
    
    console.log(aValue);
    console.log(bValue);
    
    if (aValue === "") {
        a.classList.add("red-transparent-overlay");
    } else {
        a.classList.add("green-transparent-overlay");
    }
}
```

and submitting my form when the first field is null adds red-transparent-overlay class to the first field, the same happens with the second statement, so your code is working.

Comment: I have checked console and found this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at checkPost.js:5

Comment: @DeadlyDragonnn Did you use my code or your own? If your own, please provide me code of your form.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove the other class when you add a class.

```
    if (aValue === "") {
        a.classList.add("red-transparent-overlay");
        a.classList.remove("green-transparent-overlay");
    } else {
        a.classList.add("green-transparent-overlay");
        a.classList.remove("red-transparent-overlay");
    }
```